# 'DocumentReference' object has no attribute 'push'

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, reference

I'm writing an app in Python that used Firestore/Firebase! I've got the database all set up. Now I've managed to add an account number into the database *see below*. Now each time the program runs it just writes over the already added account number! I don't know what to do!

[Adding account number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TS1S.png)

Here is my database set up

[Database setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5d0u.png)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to add multiple fields with the same fieldname, maybe consider using an array which contains all account numbers for that document?

Comment: @MCcereal I found that you can use the .push() method but it has to be a reference so it would be like db.reference('database/collection) then doc_ref.push().set({...}) but it errors out because I cannot reference it right! I've tried db.reference('bankproject-59a1a/Clients') but it just errors out.